# jQuery issue. Button clicked when trying to use remove()

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome-extension, youtube-api

I have a problem when my 'removeclass' button is pressed. The remove button is supposed to remove a button.  It does this, but the button is also pressed, which is not supposed to happen and changes the video player time.

How can I disable the button before removal?  I have tried using .prop("disabled", true) with no luck.

```
 //remove button function
$("body").on("click",".removeclass", function(e){ 
    var site = document.URL;
    if (site.includes('#')) {
        site = site.substring(0, site.length - 1);
    }
    $(this).parent('div').children().prop("disabled", true);
    timearray = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem(site));
    timepoint = parseInt($(this).parent('div').attr("id"), 10);
    var index = timearray.indexOf(timepoint);
    if (index > -1) {
        timearray.splice(index, 1);
        localStorage.setItem(site, JSON.stringify(timearray));
        console.log(JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem(site)));
        $(this).parent('div').remove();
    }
});

//Creates button
function createButton(timepoint) {
    var dispTime = convertTime(parseInt(timepoint, 10));
    var r = $('<div id='+ timepoint + ' style="float: left"> <input type="button"  ID='+ timepoint + ' value=' + dispTime + '> <a href="#" class="removeclass">Remove</a> </div>');
    timepoint = parseInt(timepoint, 10);
    r.click(function() {
        $('video').get(0).currentTime = timepoint;
    });

    $("#watch-headline-title").append(r);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Original code pared down to demo the problem:

The "button" action handler (placed on the `<div>`) is called prior to the `.removeclass` handler:**

```js
//Removed lines not needed to demo problem
//Changed HTML to give unique IDs to the <div> and <input>

//remove button function
$("body").on("click",".removeclass", function(e){ 
    console.log('In .removeclass click handler.');
    $(this).parent('div').children().prop("disabled", true);
    console.log('Removing');
    $(this).parent('div').remove();
});

//Creates button
function createButton(timepoint) {
    var dispTime = timepoint; //changed for testing convertTime() not provided
    var r = $('<div id='+ timepoint + ' style="float: left"> <input type="button"  ID='+ timepoint + ' value=' + dispTime + '> <a href="#" class="removeclass">Remove</a> </div>');
    r.click(function(e) {
        console.log('In <div> "button" click handler.');
    });
    $("#watch-headline-title").append(r);
}
createButton('the-Div-button');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="watch-headline-title"></div>
```

The simplest solution to this is to have your "button" event handler placed on the `<input>` instead of the `<div>`.

You can do this by changing the line:

```
r.click(function() {
```

to

```
r.find('input').click(function() {
```

When you do so, only the `.removeclass` handler is called when you click remove:

```js
//Removed lines not needed to demo problem
//Changed HTML to give unique IDs to the <div> and <input>

//remove button function
$("body").on("click",".removeclass", function(e){ 
    console.log('In .removeclass click handler.');
    $(this).parent('div').children().prop("disabled", true);
    console.log('Removing');
    $(this).parent('div').remove();
});

//Creates button
function createButton(timepoint) {
    var dispTime = timepoint; //changed for testing convertTime() not provided
    var r = $('<div id='+ timepoint + ' style="float: left"> <input type="button"  ID='+ timepoint + ' value=' + dispTime + '> <a href="#" class="removeclass">Remove</a> </div>');
    r.find('input').click(function(e) {
        console.log('In <input> "button" click handler.');
    });
    $("#watch-headline-title").append(r);
}
createButton('the-Div-button');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="watch-headline-title"></div>
```

Note: The IDs you assign to both your `<div>` and `<input>` are identical. This should not be the case.  In addition, you do not put double quotes around these IDs in your HTML.  Thus, depending on what is passed to `createButton`, the HTML may be invalid.

Comment: Hello! @Mayken.  This fixed it perfectly! Thank you for the help.

Answer (score 1):

```
//You should to use e.preventDefault(); at first line of function asfollowing.

//Please try and let me know if not fixed.  

$("body").on("click",".removeclass", function(e){ 
    e.preventDefault(); // Please add this line here
    var site = document.URL;
    if (site.includes('#')) {
        site = site.substring(0, site.length - 1);
    }
    $(this).parent('div').children().prop("disabled", true);
    timearray = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem(site));
    timepoint = parseInt($(this).parent('div').attr("id"), 10);
    var index = timearray.indexOf(timepoint);
    if (index > -1) {
        timearray.splice(index, 1);
        localStorage.setItem(site, JSON.stringify(timearray));
        console.log(JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem(site)));
        $(this).parent('div').remove();
    }
});
```

Comment: Hi thank you for your response.  Unfortunately e.preventDefault(); did not fix the bug and the button is still clicked.  Also the script is inside a content script in the extension.

Comment: @pcpetepete, & Obaidul Kader, This will not work. By the time the `.removeclass` event handler is called, the other handler has already been executed. `preventDefault()` can not prevent something that has already happened.  In addition, even if this handler was called prior to the other one, the other handler is not the default action.  Thus, `preventDefault()` would still be ineffective at preventing it from being called.